Does memory paging affect performance without memory mapping?
Cache line alignment is considered when designing efficient data structures with no doubt.
However I wonder, in a scenario with no IO swapping or memory mapping, if page alignment matters for efficiency?
I will state my understanding of the related mechanisms, this possibly hilarious question may derive from some essential mistakes.

As the memory address translation involving page tables, if data is grouped within the same page, it could indeed improve locality since the page table entry is more likely to be cached in the TLB.
But this doesn’t mean all data within a page gets loaded to the CPU at once — the CPU still loads data by cache line size.
So, the page alignment may enhance address translation efficiency. However, it wouldn’t lead to simultaneous access of all data within a single page, as cache line alignment would.

Is my understanding correct, particularly regarding page alignment’s importance only in scenarios with address translation?
Sincerely appreciate any advice or suggestions, thank you!
